# Can I use the timeline to erase keyframes?

Tags: animation, workflow

Is it possible to use the green bar in the *Timeline* to erase keyframes?

[image]

Is there someway to do something like erasing keyframes by scrolling over them *instead of removing them one by one*?

Comment: Related to this question : http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/move-keyframes-from-timeline

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## For 2.8 and newer:

This is now possible. Keys are shown as diamonds, like in the dope sheet. Mark them and hit X to delete them.

## For 2.79 and earlier:

**No**; not in the timeline.
This is done in the [Dope Sheet](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/dope_sheet/index.html).

- Hit <kbd>B</kbd> to select with a rectangle (or any other selection
  method).
- Hit <kbd>X</kbd> to delete selected keyframes.

  [image: Delete keyframes]

Comment: So it can't be done with the timeline? (I was thinking maybe something would be possible with auto keying)

Comment: As far as I can tell, nope. The timeline is really limited to simply viewing the keyframes. There's not much more you can do other than that.

Comment: Dope sheet link seems broken.

Answer (score 20):

It is possible to delete the keyframes from the 3D view without having to have one of the animation views visible but it doesn't remove the problem of having to delete the keyframes one by one.

1. Move to the timeline marker to the frame that has the keyframe you want to delete.
2. With the cursor in the 3D view press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and choose 'Delete Keyframe'.

This will delete *all* keyframes on the current frame but still has to be done on every separate frame.

Answer (score 6):

There is another way to erase keyframes (This method allows you to select precisely which property to delete key):

- Within the timeline, move the playhead over the keyframe you want to erase.
- Found the properties which are animated at this keyframe (for instance, `location`).
- Right-click on it, and select *Delete keyframes*, or *Delete Single Keyframe* (the first will delete all 3 *location* property keys, and the second only the property you right-clicked on, i.e. X, Y, or Z).

  [image: deleting keyframes]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would have to do this one by one. (why not just press Alt+I?)

Comment: It is good info, but I did say in my question (maybe it was a bit vague..) that I did not want to remove keyframes one by one.

Comment: Exact. I'm confused. Well, as @CharlesL said, it's not possible :)

Answer (score 3):

The given answers are ok for a few objects with keyframes, but if you have a lot of objects. Then select all objects, go in the graph editor and hit <kbd>A</kbd> to select all keyframes. Then <kbd>X</kbd> to delete all selected. All keyframes are gone in more less steps.

Comment: This works not only on the graph editor but on the dope sheet as well.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to the timeline and click the keyframe you want to delete.
2. Press Space on the keyboard and type 'Delete Keyframe'.
3. Click it twice.

Comment: This doesn't allow to delete multiple keyframes as was asked.