# Image not rendering correctly

Tags: rendering

I am doing a very rough render for a school project and when I try to render it it comes out completely different than in the 3d view
[image: this is how it looks like when rendered.]

[image: and the second is what it looks like in 3d view.]

I suspect this is because of the yellow/gold dimensions bars on the right but I have no idea what they are or how to change them.

Comment: Those yellow things mean that there is a keyframe.

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2993/can-i-use-the-timeline-to-erase-keyframes/2996#2996

Comment: i can't see from the screenshots that you have provided but since you have keyframed the dimensions of an object "the yellowish thing" ... could it be that you re rendering out a frame which is different from the viewport?